# how to extract topical key phrases using mallet

Tags: machine-learning, mining, mallet

I have imported the file in mallet, now I want to model topic from the imported data and store them in a text file, from where I will be able to read those topics. Can anyone help in writing the commands for topic extraction, as I typed command below for topic extraction but it throws exception.

bin\mallet import-dir --input D:\Data\test1 --output test1.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --extra-stopwords extra.txt

by removing --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --extra-stopwords extra.txt i am able to import file after that, when I try to train model exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use GUI for mallet.

https://code.google.com/p/topic-modeling-tool/